# Watching a vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have the following store.

MyStore.vue

```
export default {
  namespaced:true,
  state: {
    data: [],
  }
  // actions, mutations, etc
}
```

I would like to know when new data arrives in the store.

MyOtherVueFile.vue

```
export default {
  computed: {
    getFoo() {
      return this.$store.state.MyStore.data;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    getFoo(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(`New ${JSON.stringify(newValue)}`);
      console.log(`Old ${JSON.stringify(oldValue)}`);
    }
  },
}
```

However the console always shows the new and old data to be the same object.  Is this the correct syntax for doing so?

FYI - I need to capture when new items are added to the vuex store data, as I am adding them directly to an OpenLayers Map.

Comment: Can you provide the code for where this is used? Depending on the usage, you shouldn't need to watch vuex store values as they are reactive.

Comment: You need to initialize the `MyStore`, etc. in state: {...} to make the data reactive

Comment: Sorry, but what I am trying to do goes a bit outside of reactivity since I am dealing with OpenLayers

Answer (score 8):

I solved it via

```
this.$store.subscribe((mutation,state) => {
  if (mutation.type === 'myStore/MyMutation') {
    const myData = mutation.payload.data.forEach(x=> etc...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can watch a store property directly like this:

```
watch:{
  '$store.state.data'(value, oldValue) {
  }
}
```

You can also use the 'deep' and 'handler' syntax to watch sub properties on an object.

If you want the old data for an array, you will need to make deep or shallow copy in the watch handler and maintain it in the component.

Unfortunately when working with objects and arrays, you will not be able to see the old state of the object, with the new state, unless the actual object changes (replacing, not mutating).

Comment: So there is no way to tell when a new object is added to the array (other than manually looping through and interrogating it)?

Comment: Is subscribe/subscribeAction able to handle namespaced stores? If so that may be what I'm looking for...? https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch

Comment: If you need a deep compare you can use an object compare library, or do a nifty hack like JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b) to do a deep compare.  You can speed that up by pre-checking the array lengths.

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46097506/1706618 there is another way to watch store changes