# Vue if condition is met but doesnt show result

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I got a v-if and if the Condition is true it should show some other vue elements

```
<template v-if="$store.state.Zell_Open[$store.state.PAGENUMBER]===true">
```

my state:

```
Zell_Open: [false],
PAGENUMBER: 0
```

When i change Zell_Open to true the component that should be shown is not shown, it will only be shown when i manually change the PAGENUMBER state (via Vue Dev tools) one up and one down, then the component that should be shown is shown.

I tried to use this as a work around and tryied to just change the PAGENUMBER state one up and one down when the Zell_open state is udated but this doesnt work too, it only works when using dev tools.

I also tried using v-show in a v-div instead of a v.if but that also just resulted in the same problem.

EDIT:
I tried using computed variables and i tried using getters instead of directly using the state but the i still got the same problem

To clarify:
It worked when i just used

```
<template v-if="$store.state.Zell_Open===true">
```

That was before the Zell_Open state was an array, there it worked.
So i think the `[$store.state.PAGENUMBER]` is causing the problem.

Comment: What happens if you move that into a computed property, and use that computed prop in the `v-if` binding?

Comment: I also tried this before, the same happens.

Comment: Hey, try using a getter instead of directly accessing the store state.

Comment: @MohibArshi still the same problem

Comment: @Terry sorry forget to @ you.  In a computed property the same problem still occures.

Comment: @Erik, how do you update Zell_Open?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I watch synchronously a state change in vuex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46096261/how-can-i-watch-synchronously-a-state-change-in-vuex)

Comment: @ZdravkoPernikov via Mutation

Comment: @NicolasDurant sadly no, it worked and updated when it wasnt an array. So it was watched correctly before.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Vue.set** in your store mutations:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

And definitely move " $store.state.Zell_Open[$store.state.PAGENUMBER] === true " into a computed property. This way your template will remain clean of any logic.

Answer (score -1):

You either have to make a getter in your Vuex store, then a computed property on the component and watch it like Vue data, or you can use a Vuex watcher to react on the changes. Vuex provides a watcher method [Vuex watcher method](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch) like Vue's that you can use to watch for changes.

```
this.$store.watch(
  (state)=>{
    return this.$store.getters.your_getter
  },
  (val)=>{
   //something changed do something

  },
  {
    deep:true // when you have to watch arrays or objects
  }
  );
```

Comment: Yeah didn't know that. I will have to try that in a project and no worries :) The more you know